# Select user status and select date less today in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have this query:

```
$sqlquery="SELECT * FROM tableusers WHERE status = 'off' IN (SELECT DATE(mydate) AS mydate FROM tableusers where mydate < CURDATE()) ";
```

This return:

```
off
off
on
```

This should return pure off:

```
off
off
off
```

How can I just return user status according to old day with condition less that today?

Comment: `WHERE status = 'off' IN ....` doesn't really make a whole lot of sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but I didn't get your question clearly, and I don't have enough reputation for comment. Below is one solution which you can try:

`SELECT * FROM tableusers WHERE status = 'off' AND mydate < CURDATE()`

This will return all the rows, where **status** is **off** and **mydate** is less than **CURDATE()** that is today.

Please elaborate your question so that we can understand it clearly. What is the purpose of your query? What output are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableusers
WHERE status = 'off' IN (SELECT DATE(mydate) AS mydate
                         FROM tableusers 
                         WHERE mydate < CURDATE()
                        );
```

Do you see anything wrong with it?  Most databases would fail with a syntax error somewhere near the `IN`.

It is a very unusual construct, so I'm not sure if it is parsed as:

```
WHERE (status = 'off') IN (SELECT DATE(mydate) FROM tableusers WHERE mydate < CURDATE());
```

or:

```
WHERE status = ( 'off' IN (SELECT DATE(mydate) FROM tableusers WHERE mydate < CURDATE()) )
```

I am guessing the latter (based on the fact that some rows are returned).  The "`off` IN" portions returns a boolean, which gets treated as 0.  Both `'on'` and `'off'` would be converted to numbers for the comparison -- and hence 0 = 0 and either value matches.

I would suggest that you compare dates to dates.  I don't, however, know the logic that you really intend.

Comment: Hi Gordon,  about your question:  RE: Do you see anything wrong with it? Most databases would fail with a syntax error.  I used Mariadb and I not have error, when I run:  WHERE status = ( 'off' IN (SELECT DATE(mydate) FROM tableusers WHERE mydate < CURDATE()) )  I get error:  ****    mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in    ***   other error: *** You have an error  MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT DATE(mydate) AS mydate FROM myusers where mydate < CURDATE())' at line 1 ***  this error no happens when I run my first query.